# Realm-CLI pull failed: (403 Forbidden)

Tags: mongodb, realm

I am currently trying to import a realm app on Xcode ,but whenever I run the command "realm-cli pull --remote="app-id"" with app-id substituted with my actual app id, I get the error saying "pull failed: (403 Forbidden) Please check your Atlas API Whitelist entries to ensure that requests from this IP address are allowed". On the mongodb atlas dashboard, I have it enabled so that all IP addresses are able to access the app and do the command, but event then, I still get the same error. My realm-cli is the beta version 2.0.0-beta.7. I have no clue what the error could be, so any advice will help.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's important to post clear questions; keeping in mind that what's clear to you may not be clear to us. For example, what does *import a realm app on Xcode* mean? Where in the console are you setting this *so that all IP addresses are able to access the app*. Then, what is your exact code to get the app? Are you remembering to remove the <> from around the IP key?

Comment: Yes, I still have to used to posting clear questions. Importing a realm app just means connecting the swift app to Realm. For the console, I went to network access in the mongodb account dashboard for the atlas cluster I want to use to store information and the network access reads 0.0.0.0/0, so that any IP address is able to read it. The code I wrote is irrelavant since realm-cli is a terminal tool. Can you ellaborate on what you mean when you say " Are you remembering to remove the <> from around the IP key?"

Comment: If you see this `realm-cli login --api-key="<my api key>"` in the docs, it actually means `realm-cli login --api-key="xxxxxxxxxx"` with no < >

Comment: *The code I wrote is irrelavant* - no, it's very relevant. Installing Realm is 'code', connecting to realm is 'code'. You could have a simple typo in one of the commands (code) that's causing it to malfunction. You may not be logging in before pulling etc. Is the API key scoped correctly? For help, details must be provided... and really important, your coding platform (which should also be a tag). Lastly posting qustions about BETA software is generally not a good idea because BETA software can be somewhat dynamic and a correct answer today may not be correct tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

The API keys used for `realm-cli login` have certain set of permissions. To be able to fully use an API key you need to set specific access.

- open realm web console and select project you want to configure
- click on three dots menu close to the project dropdown list, open "project settings"
- open "Access manager" tab and select "API keys"
- set your API key as "Project owner"

I've struggled with 403 error after `realm-cli push`.
After making an api key "project owner" there was no need of adding IPs to the whitelist, it started to work right away.